# popup window sin plugin en Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

He creado una ventana emergente con html, css y js todo en un archivo .html, Quiero incorporar dicho popup en el "home page" que estoy diseñando en Wordpress con Avada Theme y que se vea nada mas al cargar la pagina. Ya he probado con multiples plugins y no funcionan. En qué carpeta de wordpress o Avada theme coloco este archivo html (popup) y desde donde llamo la función para que aparezca en el home page??

```
function popup(mylink, windowname) { 
    if (! window.focus)return true; 

    var href; 
    if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href=mylink; 
    else href=mylink.href; 

    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes'); 
    return false;
} 

<BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, de preferencia trata de añadir tu código para saber que has intentado de lo contrario tu pregunta sera candidata a cerrarse.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida Gemasoft! El problema está en que no se donde colocar este archivo html que he creado. El código que tengo en mente para llamarlo es el siguiente

Comment: function popup(mylink, windowname) { if (! window.focus)return true; var href; if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href=mylink; else href=mylink.href; window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes'); return false; }
<BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">

Comment: ahora necesito saber donde ponerlo, eso es todo. Soy nuevo en Wordpress y ando perdido y nuevo en esto, por lo que pido disculpas de antemano

Comment: Ya lo coloque en tu pregunta

Comment: Vale, ya veo a lo que te referías, te lo agradezco de veras, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer el siguiente proceso :

1) Implementar el JS en un archivo dentro de la carpeta js del theme , suele estar en la siguiente ruta /wp-content/themes/avada/js/ allí puedes crear un archivo por ejemplo scripts.js

2) En el archivo functions.php del mismo theme puedes registrar el JS --> http://www.ida.cl/blog/desarrollo/como-usar-javascript-wordpress/

3) Para Insertar esta linea en el Body debes buscar el archivo header.php de la plantilla y editar la linea para ingresar el llamdo de onload :

```
 <BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">
```

Con este proceso podrías que el código quede montado en WP.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo.

Comment: Si te sirve la respuesta no olvides calificarla.